# Reporting services 2012 Report Manager menu url not using HTTPS

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, reporting-services-2012

I have recently set up a new instance of SQL Server Reporting Services. I have it running and am in the testing phase of the deploy. I have set it up to use SSL and basic Authentication. This all works. The report writer has been able to deploy reports and start testing. In this testing we discovered that the menu on the left of the report manager in the data sources or reports management window will not use https. So let me explain it more.

If you browse to a report or data source in Report Manager then highlight and click on the down arrow and choose "Manage" you will get a page with the report's or data sources' properties. It will also have a menu on the left with items like "Subscriptions", "Dependent items", and "Security". If I click on one of these items I get a 404 page error. I can then go to the url and simply put a 's' in the http so it read https and it will work.

Due to security requirements I have had to block all port 80 traffic, if I open port 80 it will work. It only works as http with port 80 open. The menu url never defaults to htts.

I have set the root url to have an https at the front. This made no change.

I tried setting the ReportServerUrl in the `c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSRS11.MSSQLSERVER\Reporting Services\ReportServer\rsreportserver.config` file. I set it to include the https at the front as such `https://DNSentry.com/reports`. Yes I changed the url so the Reports is the Report Manager. This broke the entire Report Manager. It would give me an error of:

> The attempt to connect to the report server failed. Check your
>   connection information and that the report server is a compatible
>   version.

I have also tried to force report portal to use https by setting the `secureconnectionlevel` in `\c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSRS11.MSSQLSERVER\Reporting Services\ReportServer\rsreportserver.config` to 2, then to 1 and it gave me an error both times.

> The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on
>   a send.

If anyone knows how to force Reporting services to use https for all urls or if I am doing something wrong please let me know.

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this? I also have the same issue, and this was the best info I could find http://forums.asp.net/t/1299521.aspx?Report+Manager+Links+with+SSL (but I haven't had a chance to try it out yet)

Answer (score 0):

I bet if you use the SSRS tool at All Programs/Microsoft SQL Server XXX/Configuration Tools/Reporting Services/Configuration Manager you can set the site to use ssl. You should ensure that you have a valid ssl certificate.

After that, verify that the client application is sending over https.

Are you using custom authentication?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am relatively familiar with the Configuration Manager it is how I have set it to use https. This works for 95% of the site. It is just this one menu that seems to not work. Unless there is a setting that I am not aware of I have found no way to force this menu to use https in the configuration manager. 

Also no we are not using a custom authentication, just Active Directory. We do pull info about who can see what in some reports from databases but authentication and security is AD based.

Comment: That is very odd indeed. So login and all request up to the point where the manage data source hyperlink is clicked are made using https but the request to get the data source subscription data is using http?

Comment: I agree this is very odd. I have not seen anything like it before. 

Ya it is all using htps and works great except the menu. It is the whole menu though not just the data source subscription item. It is Subscription, Dependent Items, Security and Properties. You can get to the properties but if you go to another page like Security and add the 's' when you click on Properties to go back you have to add the 's' again.

Comment: I just ran this through fiddler and am now seeing a 401 status being returned when the manage report dropdown item is selected. The page comes back, as you said, with no https after a 302 redirect. This smells of a misconfiguration in forms authentication on the server. The only other thing I can think of is some resource being accessed in a non ssl friendly manner, however I am not seeing that in fiddler.

Answer (score 0):

1. RS configuration wizard, bind https for both manager and service urls.
2. Do a manual check in config, see description below, I put `2`.

Finally, the following line in RSReportServer.config governs the master control over SSL:

```
<Add Key="SecureConnectionLevel" Value="2"/>
```

Acceptable values are:

`3` -  Most secure—Use SSL for absolutely everything.
`2` - Secure—Use SSL for rendering and methods that pass credentials but don't insist on it for all SOAP calls.
`1` - Basic Security—Accepts http but rejects any calls that might be involved in the passing of credentials.
`0` - Least Secure—Don't use SSL at all.

`2` is the value that the installation wizard will input if you install with the Use SSL check box selected, but we prefer to use `3` and ensure that the Report Manager is also using SSL.